# Error 413 on portal.azure - ASP.Net Core 2.1 Api

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to upload large files to my ASP.Net Core 2.1 Api.
The files i'm uploading are aproximately 500mb in size.
On my local machine the uploading occurs flawlessly. The problem occurs when I'm uploading to protal.azure using my api app service. Does anyone know where I could increase the aspmaxrequestentityallowed somewhere on azure?

I've tried setting the appsettings.json on my vs project, although no luck on deployment. I've searched through all the settings on azure and even added a few variables like following image. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check a couple of things?

1. Is there any WAF (like Application gateway) deployed in front of your web app in your Azure environment? If yes, can you check by temporarily disabling it to understand whether the restriction is imposed by WAF or the app service.
2. While running locally, are you running on self hosted (kestrel) or IIS express?

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like setting up azure is more complicated than programming.
I solved this problem by:

1. Splitting a file in javascript using blobs on upload.
2. I then created a datastructure on the backend which collects the blobs.
3. Only logged in authenticated users can use this feature of course, which makes it
   easy to store blob packets on the backend with my newly created datastructure*cough
   dictionary*.
4. On the last upload file, I send a status "2" which means the blobs have been sent
   successfully
5. On the backend I concatenated the byte[][] into a stream which I then could save to a
   blob storage i.e. file.

Basically using this method, I never send data which exceeds 30mb, which is below the limit. As long as the backend has enough memory to handle temporary byte streams, we should be able to upload files any size we want, which is fantastic....Mission accomplished.